# Nancy Fx Razor views how to show or hide elements based on user roles

Tags: forms, authentication, roles, element, nancy

I am playing with Nancy and Forms Authentication. I have a layout view that shows a login or a logout link depending on whether or not the user is authenticated:

```
 @if (@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated())
            {
                <p><small><span style="padding-right:15px"><em>@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.UserName</em></span>
                    <a href="@Url.Content("~/logout")">Logout</a></small></p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p><small><a href="@Url.Content("~/login")">Login</a></small></p>
            }
```

Throughout my app I will have elements that need to be visible only to those with the correct role.
My question is this. What is the best way to handle this? Should I check for the role in the view and then show/hide the element or in the module show different views depending on the user role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using partial views in my layout to provide different navigation sections based on permissions.

```
@if (@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated())
     {
        if (@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.Claims.Contains("Admin"))
        {
            @Html.Partial("Views/Partials/_AdminMenu")
        }
        else if (@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.Claims.Contains("Editor"))
        {
            @Html.Partial("Views/Partials/_EditorMenu")
        }
         else if (@Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser.Claims.Contains("Viewer"))
        {
            @Html.Partial("Views/Partials/_ViewerMenu")
        }
         else
         {
            @Html.Partial("Views/Partials/_PublicMenu")
         }
     }
     else
     {
         @Html.Partial("Views/Partials/_PublicMenu")
     }
```

I will render different views from the module if there are significant differences and send the user to a "permission denied" type view if the get to somewhere they are not supposed to.

I found this to redirect the user to a denied view. Add an after hook to the top of the module.

```
 public class EditUserRoleModule : NancyModule
    {
        public EditUserRoleModule()
        {
        // add an after hook to send the user to access denied if they are NOT admin
        After += context =>
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                context.Response = this.Response.AsRedirect("/denied");
        };

        this.RequiresAnyClaim(new[] { "admin" });
```